# Am I ok to call a function with a variable that might not be set?

Tags: php

I am creating functions in my code to clean it up, one of them is for working out the offset for pagination.

The function is

```
function pageOffSet($page, $count, $resultsPerPage) {
     // WORK OUT HIGHEST PAGE NUMBER
     $pageCount = ceil($count / $resultsPerPage);
     // IF GET PAGE VARIABLE IS HIGHER THAN MAX PAGE POSSIBLE
     if (isset($page) && $page > $pageCount) {
          $page = $pageCount;
     // IF VALID GET PAGE VARIABLE
     } elseif (isset($page) && is_numeric($page) && $page > 1) { 
          $page = $page;
     // IF PAGE GET VARIABLE NOT SET
     } else { 
          $page = 1;
     }
     // OFFSET FOR POST RESULTS
     $offSet = ($page - 1) * $resultsPerPage;
     return array('offSet' => $offSet, 'resultsPerPage' => $resultsPerPage);
}
```

And I call it like,

```
$page = pageOffSet($_GET['page'], $count, 15);
```

Except `$_GET['page']` may be set or unset? I check inside the function to see if it is set or not, but is it ok to do this? I get no errors but I just want to check?

Comment: It will generate an E_NOTICE message: http://codepad.org/0Th4zTT0

Comment: Btw, I would use a default parameter value here: function pageOffSet($count, $resultsPerPage, $page=1). Then you can be sure $page is always set.

Comment: Then my pagination wouldn't work?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error will not occur, but a warning will probably be generated, depending on your error reporting settings. However, a better approach may be using an default argument:

```
function pageOffSet($count, $resultsPerPage, $page = NULL) { ... }
```

Then to check if `$page` is there, use:

```
if ($page)
```

Or to check if it's not there, use:

```
if (!$page)
```

This way, you can use the first two arguments without needing to provide the last; or you can provide all three. To use `$page`, check if it is `NULL` or not and use it accordingly.

Comment: This seems like an awesome solution, didn't know php could use scalar arguments!!

Answer (score 4):

When you access `$_GET['page']`, PHP throws a notice that the index is not set. If you do not see the notice, adjust your `ERROR_REPORTING`. You should always have notices displayed in development environment.

Use something like this to check if the variable was set (and cast to int):

```
$pageNumber = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 0;
$page = pageOffSet($pageNumber, $count, 15);
```

Comment: +1 for error reporting and casting. IMO the code would be clearer if you would put the `isset` ternary on a separate line with an intermediate variable.